# Bypassing machine precision issue when calculating the difference between two extreme probabilities generated by `pnorm()` in R

Tags: r, optimization, precision, normal-distribution, cdf

For examples, let's say I have `p1` and `p2`:

```
p1 <- pnorm(-50)
p2 <- pnorm(-49)
```

I would like to know their difference, i.e. `p2-p1`, or equivalently, `log(p2-p1)`. As expected, their directly calculated difference is identical to zero to the computer:

```
identical(p2-p1, 0)
# [1] TRUE
```

Usually, the best way to deal with extreme values in `pnorm` is to use the logarithmic value:

```
ln_p1 <- pnorm(-50, log.p = T)
ln_p2 <- pnorm(-49, log.p = T)
```

However, I don't know how to manipulate `ln_p1` and `ln_p2` and get what I need without going through extreme values.

Is there a R library with a function which directly returns the logarithm of the differences in the probabilities of two extreme quantiles? As in the above example, maybe something like: `pnorm_between(-50, -49, log.p = T)`?

---

**Why I am doing this:**

I am working on an optimization **(maximization)** problem over `p2-p1` (or `log(p2-p1)`) using the `optim()` function. The initial condition is occasionally unavoidably very extreme leading to extreme values of `p2` and `p1`, in which case the function is unable to iterate itself over the gradient which is almost flat. Although it is possible to tweak the required precision but the initial condition is also highly variable and thus it is not known what precision is sufficient. Therefore, I am thinking about transforming the optimization to the logarithmic or logit scale, but have been unable to do so...

Comment: If the difference between two values is zero, their quotient equals 1, i.e. p1/p2 = 1. Take the logarithm: log(p1/p2) = log(p1) - log(p2) = 0. So, just minimize `(ln_p1 - ln_p2)^2`.

Comment: Note, this potentially could cause troubles with the gradient and optimizer. I haven't considered this at all and I'm not stating that doing as suggested would be the best approach. Optimization is not my speciality and there might be better approaches out there. I *think*  it should work though.

Comment: Sorry I didnt make it clear @Roland. It is a maximization problem. I have supplemented the question.